# Mobile detect function is not working in my site.

Tags: php, html, css

i want to open my site in different way when it is open in mobile device. and for desktop computer it remains same. 
for this i am using this code in index.php file.

```
 <body>
    <?php include ('Mobile_Detect.php');
      $detect = new Mobile_Detect;
      if ( $detect->isMobile() ) {
      } ?>
        <?php include ('bground.php'); ?>
        <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="containe">
            <main id="main" role="main">
               <div class="promo-img">
                <div id="myDiv" style="width:1000px; height:250px;">
                </div>
               </div>
        </div>
  </body>
```

but its give me error
    Fatal error: Class 'Mobile_Detect' not found in /home/test/public_html/index.php on line 12

can please anyone help me. how can i detect my mobile device. and as i open my site in different way on mobile.

Comment: please suggest me another appropriate solution if this way is not perfect.

Comment: How are you install Mobile_Detect class ? From composer ?

Comment: i just pick this file Mobile_Detect.php from internet. and follow the instruction to detect the mobile device. but its not working.

Comment: if this is not a good way to do detect. please refer me any other solution with example. thanks

Comment: this is well solutuon for your goal.

Comment: Which framework you are using? or doing it in procedural approach?

Comment: I'm using simple boostrap . and using PDO in php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply wrote a function that detect user agent (browser) base on operating system and return true or false.

```
<?php 
   function isMobile(){
      if(preg_match('/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])||preg_match('/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i',substr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],0,4))){
        return true;
      }
      else{
       return false;
      }
  } // end of function 

         if(isMobile()){
            echo 'you are on mobile device.';
           // Do something on mobile 
         }
         else{
          echo 'you are not on mobile device';
          // Do something when you are not mobile.
         }
?>
```

It will return true if you are navigating through a mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

You wrong with path to Mobile_Detect.php
Check the right way to Mobile_Detect.php file

Comment: move your Mobile_Detect.php file to /home/test/public_html/Mobile_Detect.php and replace include ('Mobile_Detect.php'); to 
include ('/home/test/public_html/Mobile_Detect.php');

Comment: what if using composer?